# Use result for next iterative step in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop, iteration, repeat

I am new to iterative computation R. I want to do a serial computation sucn as that I use a previous result in the next one. The code below shows one attempt of a code to compute serial difference equation:

```
quadmap <- function(start,rho,niter) {
  #variables
  x_1<- start
  r<-rho
  n<-niter
  print(c('x_1','r','n'))
  print(c(x_1,r,n))  
  
  for (i in 1:n){
  x_k_1<-x_1
  xk <-  r*x_k_1*(1-x_k_1)
  x_k_1<- xk
  
  print(xk)
  
  }
  
}
```

I want to use the new xk as the new 'x_k_1' in the calculation until n loops.

I am not getting the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in recursive version, here is an example

```
quadmap <- function(start,rho,niter) {
  if (niter == 1) return(start)
  x <- quadmap(start,rho,niter-1)
  c(x,rho*tail(x,1)*(1-tail(x,1)))
}
```

**Example**

```
> quadmap(0.5,1,5)
[1] 0.5000000 0.2500000 0.1875000 0.1523438 0.1291351

> quadmap(0.8,3,5)
[1] 0.8000000 0.4800000 0.7488000 0.5642957 0.7375982
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is going on? I see you assign the function to x before you start computing. Also please explain the use of tail(). Thanks.

Comment: @user1916067 `x` is a vector that contains all values from the first `n-1` iterations. To add the current value, we fetch last element `tail(x,1)` and put it into the formula, and append `rho*tail(x,1)*(1-tail(x,1))` to the existing `x` as the output of current iteration.

Answer (score 0):

A second attempt gives me the desired outcome:

```
quadmap <- function(start,rho,niter) {
  #variables
  x_1<- start
  r<-rho
  n<-niter
  print(c('x_1','r','n'))
  print(c(x_1,r,n))
  
 
 for(i in 1:n) {
    x_1 <-  r* x_1*(1- x_1)
    
    print(x_1)
  
 }
}
```